# Strange bug with date calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have to calculate how many years passed between two dates. My code works fine - except for very specific dates.

The code bellow should produce the same year difference for both `dateEnd` and `dateEnd1`, however they are not equal. If I would change year from 2003 to 2004, it would become equal. If I would leave the year, but change from march to february, it would again be equal.

I guess it has something to do with leap years, but I am clueless why? Especially since there were 4 leap years in that period, but the year miscalculation happens for dates which are one day apart only.

I expect year difference to be 12 in both of these cases, however I get 13 in the first case with the `dateEnd` variable

```
var dateStart = '2003,03,11';
var dateEnd = '2016,03,10';
var dateEnd1 = '2016,03,09';

var difference = (new Date(dateEnd)).getTime() - (new Date(dateStart)).getTime();
difference = (new Date(difference)).getFullYear() - 1970;
alert('Between ' + dateStart + ' and ' + dateEnd + ' elapsed ' + difference + ' years.');
difference = (new Date(dateEnd1)).getTime() - (new Date(dateStart)).getTime();
difference = (new Date(difference)).getFullYear() - 1970;
alert('Between ' + dateStart + ' and ' + dateEnd1 + ' elapsed ' + difference + ' years.');
```

Here is the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgDAL/#run). One person in the comments managed to reproduce the problem on his [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFJgt/1/)!

Here are values of variables I get

```
dateStart time: 1047337200000
dateEnd time: 1457564400000
dateEnd1 time: 1457478000000
Time difference for the first case: 410227200000
Between 2003,03,11 and 2016,03,10 elapsed 13 years.
Time difference for the second case: 410140800000
Between 2003,03,11 and 2016,03,09 elapsed 12 years.
```

Comment: it is equal? I got 12 for both

Comment: Sorry, your question is slightly confusing.  Could you just specifically spell out what the above code is outputting for you and what you expect it to output.  Because what I am seeing on this fiddle is exactly the same for both.

Comment: @Steve sorry, I added what I expect to get, and what I actually get.

Comment: @bobek really? even on jsfiddle it shows me different result

Comment: What browser are you on?  I am on Chrome 25/Mac and I get 12 for both.

Comment: @bobek I checked Chrome, Firefox and Opera on Windows. I can put screenshots too :-)

Comment: Could this be a locale issue? According to our profiles, bobek and I are in the US (and I get 12 for both as well) while you are in Belgium. And from what I can see from MDN, "03/11/2003" does not be appear to be a supported format for constructing a date although MSDN says IE should like it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, even running it in jsfiddle. What version of JS, out of curiosity? http://www.computerhope.com/cgi-bin/systeminfo.cgi Try see what version it says. I couldn't get the results you had previously mentioned. After reading other people's comments, it would seem to be either specific to your machine/browser configuration.

Comment: @DocMax I updated format for constructing the date, and I also tried without string, but with `date(2003,03,10)`. Still same issue. I attached screenshot as well

Comment: change the code to print out all variables separately. It will allow us to see exactly where the difference is.

Comment: Daylight saving time is likely the problem. In the US this year, it was on March 10.

Comment: @bobek I have updated the code together with variable output

Comment: @SalmanA I tried, it made no difference unfortunately

Comment: If you only want years, would it be better to simply subtract the years and not worry about seconds, minutes, hours, and days?  `(new Date(dateEnd)).getFullYear() - (new Date(dateStart)).getFullYear())`

Comment: What about if you change from March to April?  If it is still a problem, that suggests a confusion with leap year this year.

Comment: @dsh I cannot simply subtract years, as for example between march 2003 and january 2004 less than a year passed, so I count it as 0

Comment: @BenBarden as mentioned in the post, if I change month to April, problem is gone. If I change year to 2004, problem is gone. But I am still clueless why exactly and how to solve it

Comment: I recently fixed the jsfiddle.net link. Remove any path.

Comment: Print the difference as a date rather than milliseconds. For me it is:  Fri Dec 31 1982 20:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time). Notice how close it is to crossing over to a new year.

Comment: You might consider simply comparing years, months and days (if necessary). Alternately you could convert the millisecond difference to days and divide by 365.25. It's not exact, but it might be better than the current problem you have with leap years and daylight saving time.

Comment: @SalmanA, same here "initializing the awesome", but yields output if I add "show/" to the end of the url - and I get "... elapsed 13 years", "... elapsed 12 years".

Comment: @DougDomeny Thanks for your help (and I have no idea what's with jfiddle link now, sorry about that). In the end I think I will break down dates and compare years, months and days with each other...

Comment: Here's my [own fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFJgt/), which gives "elapsed 13 years", "elapsed 13 years". Can only suggest it's nothing to do with locale.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I checked your fiddle, but if I put variables in the correct order on it (you are getting negative years, since you subtract end from start), I again get the same difference! With variables in the wrong order, both gives 13, in correct order I get 12 and 13. Can you update your fiddle?

Comment: @MarkoD, well spotted. http://jsfiddle.net/ZFJgt/1/ gives 12 / 13. That puts locale back into the frame.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I am happy someone can reproduce it finally!

Comment: I'm in UK and using Opera, BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The can/cannot reproduce difference is not the locale, but the time zone. For me (in California), the above values give:

```
alert(new Date(410140800000)); // "Thu Dec 30 1982 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
alert(new Date(410227200000)); // "Fri Dec 31 1982 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
```

Were I at or east of GMT, the second date would be "Sat Jan 1 1983...", giving the different number of years. Leap years are probably coming into it because the number of leap years is affecting the number of days in the difference.

I *thought* you would see the same thing if you use 2005/2018, but as Arjan points out, it's not quite that simple and does indeed involve leap years.

Comment: thanks for your answer. 2005/2018 produce the correct result! 2007/2020 not.

Comment: Ultimately it appears that the problem is a combination of leap days and time zones at or east of GMT.

Comment: Wed Jan 01 1975 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
Between 08/11/2007 and 08/10/2012 elapsed 5 years.  
Tue Dec 31 1974 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
Between 08/11/2007 and 08/09/2012 elapsed 4 years.

Comment: Yup. And for me the first would have been "Tue Dec 31 1974 16:00:00 GMT-0800" for 4 years, which is why I could not recreate it.

Comment: And which is why this method of date calculations is not accurate. These issues can be very hard to detect because they only appear in very specific cases.

Comment: At least I was lucky enough to find the bug as soon as I started testing random dates... Seems I will have to compare date fragments manually. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to the locale. I also get the 12 / 13 result when I change the dates to any other month in 2016, except January or February. So the reason is that 2016 is a leap year and 2003 is not.

This proves that it is not reliable to calculate date differences as dates. In order to calculate the difference in years, you need to use the year parts of both dates. Also compare the month parts, if the end month is before the start month then subtract one year and if start month and end month are the same then compare the day of the month too. You could also include hours, minutes, seconds and millis, if required.

Comment: I don't think so. it doesn't happen if I compare it with 2005 (which is not a leap year as well) or with 2004 (which is a leap year). It also happens with 2002, but not with 2001!

Comment: I get similar wrong results when I change 2003 into 2007 and/or 2016 into 2012. When you use 2005 instead of 2003 the total number of days is 365+366 days less, this could be sufficient to prevent rounding issues and therefore not produce the error.